# How can I capture and manipulate ggplot2 default axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to capture the default axis breaks from ggplot and transform them with prettyNum(). The code below works, but it creates the same plot twice, so it seems like a hack. Can the default values be captured with waiver()?

```
vec <- c(10^seq(-3,3,1))
foo.df <- data.frame("x"=vec,"y"=vec)
p <- ggplot(foo.df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10()

y_breaks <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.minor_source


ggplot(foo.df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = 10^y_breaks, labels = prettyNum(10^y_breaks))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `labels` argument in `scale_y_log10` can take a function, so you don't have to know the specific values of the default breaks. The function you pass to `labels` will transform the labels, whatever the break values happen to be. For example:

```
ggplot(foo.df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() +
  scale_y_log10(labels=prettyNum)
```

However, in your example, you're accessing the locations of the minor breaks, rather than the major breaks, so you're effectively turning the default minor breaks into custom major breaks. In that case, you can extract the minor breaks if you assign the initial plot to `p`, as you've done in your example, and then do the following, where we've used the `layer_scales` function to extract the locations of the minor breaks:

```
p + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks=10^layer_scales(p)$y$get_breaks_minor(),
                labels=prettyNum)
```

Comment: `function(x) prettyNum(x)` is the syntax you would need in that case.

Comment: I've added an example of how you could extract minor breaks from the initial plot object if you want to use those as the major breaks.

Comment: Extremely helpful. I hadn't realized that p + scale_y_log10() would overwrite the original scale of p.

Comment: Yes, you can override not only the previous `scale_***_***` functions, but also `coord_***`, `labs`, and `facet_***`.

Comment: A related question - I still don't understand the use of waiver(). If I want to change the labels, but not default values of a color, it seems I should write something like `scale_color_manual(values = waiver(), labels = c("NEW","TEXT"))` but that generates an error. What's the syntax? I can edit the question if this question isn't clear

Comment: If you're not changing the colors, but only the labels for each color, use `scale_color_discrete(labels = c("Blau","Rot"))`. You can also use the `recode` function to recode the values directly in the underlying data.